# File Attributes/Description

Tags: file, attributes, file-descriptor

I have to put some attributes on a file like you see it on an jpeg file, there you can add many attributes about the image and resolution and also but information in about the camera.

I also saw it on an mp3 file where you can add information about the song, album ,producer etc...

Is there any way to add these attributes to something like an pdf, txt.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to put some attributes on a file like you see it on an jpeg file, there you can add many attributes about the image and resolution and also but information in about the camera.

That is part of the JPEG/Exif file specification.

> I also saw it on an mp3 file where you can add information about the song, album ,producer etc...

That is part of the MP3 file specification.

> Is there any way to add these attributes to something like an pdf, txt.

[Metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Metadata) is part of the PDF file specification. There is nothing like that for plain text files.